# As Seen in Differential Equations: $\lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{\int^{\Delta}_{0} f(t+j)dj}{\Delta}=f(t^{-})$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In differential equations (and, of course, calculus), one might come across the following: for $\Delta>0,  \lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{\int^{\Delta}_{0} f(t+j)dj}{\Delta}$. Now, of course

$\lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{\int^{\Delta}_{0} f(t+j)dj}{\Delta}= \lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{\int^{u-t}_{0-t} f(u)du}{\Delta}=\lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{F(t+\Delta)-F(t)}{\Delta}=\frac{dF}{dt}=f(t)$, where $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$. I have seen, however, people expressing the above as $f(t^{-})$ -- is there any reason for this?

Comment: Take $f:x\mapsto \lceil{x\rceil}$ and $t=1$ and try to compute your limit explicitly.

Comment: It should rather be denoted by $f(t+) $ which is just a notation for $\lim_{x\to t^{+}} f(x) $.